# External library in Android studio

Tags: android

I want to add external library "

github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

" to my Android application.

I've tried to do it with Gradle sync, and I also tried with this examples.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZBPL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atTpr.jpg)

Any other way to import this lib for layout?
Can be a problem if i have a proxy connection?

I use android studio 2.1.2.

Comment: The project README contains [usage instructions](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar#usage). Follow them. If you have *specific* problems with those instructions, please explain what those problems are.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
}
```

in your build.gradle file. it is mentioned in the Readme section on github repo. of library. It is always helpfull to take a look at the documentation provided with the stuff, just my two cent.

also check if you have added

```
repositories {
jcenter()
}
```

in YourProject->build.gradle

Comment: i have add that in build.gradle and i get an error failed to resolve:org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1

Comment: Then you must be adding it in wrong file, add it to one inside YourProject -> app -> build.gradle . Note, there are two files with same name "build.gradle" .

Comment: i added i think in the right place in app/build.gradle look at image 2 from my description

Comment: check if you have added "repositories {
jcenter()
}" in YourProject->build.gradle. I tried to add that library in my project, it is working fine for me.

Comment: also in myproject/build.gradle is Ok, but from that zip that I download from github I need to put the hole folder in  my lib folder?

Answer (score 1):

if just add to external library in your project then follow these steps:

1. Copy the external library and paste into the **libs** folder which is in app folder.
2. if you can not see libs folder then change your drop down which is top left corner **android to project**. then you can see libs folder.
3. Goto to app gradle and add **dependencies** for your external library like this.

   compile files('libs/your_external_library')
4. gradle your project.

   its work for me .

Comment: i have try this method butt i got the error from screenshot

Comment: you can see the error in image 2 from my description

Comment: can you follow these step which tell you?